# C++ library integration to iPhone application

Tags: c++, iphone, integration

Thanks for your support, but will it(integration of exsisting C++ library with iPhone application) effect my application at the time of submision to Apple Store? Are there any chances of disapproval of application from Apple Store?

Comment: We can never know what Apple might start rejecting for.

I can assure you there are many apps which do you C++ libraries, and Apple accepts them fine.

Be sure to carefully check for memory leaks / problems across the objective-C / C++ barrier, I have found it a common place for mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your library is statically linked, you shouldn't have any problems with the approval process.